# Is there something like the C# verbatim identifier character for F#?

Tags: f#

Is there something like the [C# verbatim identifier character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) for F#? The reason I am asking is because every now and then I run into a member or variable in a .NET lib with a name like "to" or "for" and I am not able to assign to it because the compiler complains that it is a keyword. I know in C# you can use the @ symbol to "escape" identifiers that use a reserved keyword and while not something to be abused, it really does come in handy because when you have to, you have to. Are there any known techniques for dealing with this sort of situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, use as below, and hopefully, it will workout.

```
let ``for`` = "four"
```

Comment: He knew the concept, just needed the syntax to take a c# @for and turn it into F#.

Comment: This is what I needed, thanks. As an example, when instantiating a MailMessage class, if one wants to used named parameters, one would have to do somethings like `new MailMessage(\`\`to\`\` = "some@email.com", ...)`